# Minecraft Login Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I had been having an issue since yesterday. Whenever I log in, this message pops up:

```
Sorry, but we could not connect to our servers. Please make sure that you are online and that minecraft is not blocked (SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)
```

I'm using Minecraft launcher 1.6.44. I redownloaded Minecraft, reset my internet and reinstalled Java Edition. None of these things seem to be working!

Answer (score 1):

...the error message tells you the answer. The servers are down. Wait an hour and they'll be back up.

Answer (score -1):

make sure minecraft launcher and java exe are both allowed in your firewall.

Answer (score -2):

Hm, this has happened to me before. However, it was usually  because I had a weak or nonexistent internet connection. I'm sure you've already checked this, but my only advice would be to make sure your connection is secure and effective. I see that you have reset your internet already, but does your internet seem consistently functional on other devices? Be sure that your internet is free of problems, because that is the only issue I have ever had with not being able to log in. Minecraft doesn't let you login when you are offline, but if you have it remember your account username and password you can play offline.